# App update failure problem after distributing Android app from Google Store

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

I'm developing an Android app using Flutter and have updated the app's version and uploaded it to the Google Play Store.

However, some device models are intermittently experiencing a situation where app downloads become unavailable after updating the app.

[image]

**this popup means**

> - *Unable to install app*
> - *If the problem persists even after trying*    *again, please refer to common troubleshooting methods.*
> - *Send feedback  / OK*

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or found a solution that doesn't involve deleting the app or clearing cache?

I have met all the system app update rules mentioned in the link below and completed the app deployment,
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859350?hl=en&visit_id=638254205304451555-394873265&rd=1

but the error only occurs on some device models. Please translate the above question into English.

Comment: Have you checked the available space of the issue occured devices?

Comment: yes, this is test device so this device have enough space

Comment: check this: download the latest apk file from google play console under adb explorer (it will have same signature). And try installing it through adb command. I think it may give you more insight